# How can I turn the results of a for loop into a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I alter this for loop to turn it into a list? Thanks in advance.

```
for x in column_list:
    des, res=rp.ttest(group1= df[x][df['patients'] == 1], group1_name= "Patients",
         group2= df[x][df['patients'] == 0], group2_name= "Controls")
    res1=res.set_index('Independent t-test').T
    y=res1['Two side test p value = '].values
    if y < 0.005:
        print (x,y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall your previous question. I think something like the following may help:

```
outputList = []
for x in column_list:
    des, res=rp.ttest(group1= df[x][df['patients'] == 1], group1_name= "Patients",
         group2= df[x][df['patients'] == 0], group2_name= "Controls")
    res1=res.set_index('Independent t-test').T
    y=res1['Two side test p value = '].values
    
    #collect the values into a dictionary and append that dictionary to the outputList
    outputList.append({"x":x, "y":y})

#Now loop the list and only print the ones with appropriate p-level
for pair in outputList:
    if pair["y"] < 0.005:
        print (pair["x"],pair["y"])
```

This is moving the `print()` down into a new section of code after all of the `x,y` pairs have been collected into a list. Using a dictionary makes this all a bit cleaner.

If you want to see whats going on, you can toss `print(outputList)` before that second `for` loop and see what that output looks like. It may help connect the dots.